# Running jest in a monorepo with create-react-app packages

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, jestjs, babel-jest, monorepo

Here is a question.

I'm trying to merge some of my packages into a monorepo. I'm using `yarn` and it's `workspaces-experimental` feature. So the repository folder structure looks like:

```
.
node_modules
packages
  myapp1
  myapp2
  myreactapp1
```

Now, one of the goals is to simplify testing. I want to run `jest` in the root dir so that it runs unit tests for all the packages. And it works for `myapp1` and `myapp2` above which are node.js apps. However, `myreactapp1` is build with `create-react-app` (no eject) and uses ES6 features (like `import`) and also jsdom rendering. The tests work fine if I run them from `myreactapp1` dir with `yarn test` which pipes the code through `babel` (if I understand well). But the root jest failes on the first `import` statement.

How can I do it ?

P.S. I tried to install `babel-jest` but seems that it cannot be lauched directly from the console (windows).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [CRA does not yet work properly with Yarn Workspaces](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3405). [A workaround](https://learn.viewsdx.com/how-to-use-yarn-workspaces-with-create-react-app-and-create-react-native-app-expo-to-share-common-ea27bc4bad62) is suggested in the comments.

Anyway, to make jest work, you need to have `babel-jest` (as you said) and also a `.babelrc` file in the root folder:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```